# Summation in CPLEX with suffix tuple

Tags: cplex

I tried to get the summation in CPLEX in tuple as below, 1 element inside and 1 element outside the suffix tuple `assignment` but it got wrong.

```
    forall(<i, h> in order) {
        sum(<<w, i>, h> in assignment) J[<<w, i>, h>] <= production[<i, h>];
```

Can someone help me to explaint about it?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
tuple ordertype
{
int i;
int h;
}     
tuple assignmenttype
{
ordertype o;
int h;
}
 
{ordertype} order={<1,2>}; 
{assignmenttype} assignment={<<1,2>,3>}; 
 
int production[i in order]=i.h;
dvar int J[assignment]; 
 subject to
 {
forall(<i, h> in order) {
        sum(<<w, i>, h> in assignment) J[<<w, i>, h>] <= production[<i, h>];
        
      }        
}
```

Comment: How about if  `production` is decision variable? and the equation is `==` instead of `<=`

Comment: Hi Alex. I notice that your posts are rather poorly presented, and do not seem to involve much effort. There are case errors, chatty material is added, and punctuation is left off. Could you rectify these problems in your following posts? Technical writing is an expectation here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check this model for more undestanding why I need the `==` and `production` should be a decision variable, J is the output per worker, and production is the total each date.

```
tuple ordertype
{
int part;  // 2 parts: 1 and 2
int period;  // period 1...5
}     

tuple workerskilltype
{
int worker; // 4 workers: 1..4
int part;   // running time per worker per part
}
tuple assignmenttype
{
workerskilltype workerskill;
int h;
}

{ordertype} order = {<1,1>, <1,2>, <1,3>, <1,4>, <1,5>, <2,1>, <2,2>, <2,3>, <2,4>, <2,5>}; 
int orderQty[order] = [0,0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,5000];

{workerskilltype} workerskill = {<1,1>, <1,2>, <2,1>, <3,2>, <4,1>, <4,2>}; 

float workerSkillRunning[workerskill] = [3,7,3.5,6.5,7.8,2.9,6.7];

int step[k in 1..5] = k;
{assignmenttype} assignment={<<w, i>, h> | <w, i> in workerskill, k in 1..5, h in 1..step[k]}; 

int production[i in order]=i.period;
dvar int J[<<w, i>, h> in assignment];

dvar int+ inventory[<i, h> in order]; 
dvar int+ backorder[<i, h> in order];

dexpr float X = sum(<i, h> in order) backorder[<i, h>];

minimize X;

 subject to
 {
 forall (<i, h> in order) {
        if(h == 1){ 

            orderQty[<i, h>] == production[<i, h>]  - inventory[<i, h>] + backorder[<i, h>];    
        }       
        else {      
            orderQty[<i, h>] == production[<i, h>] + inventory[<i, h-1>]  - backorder[<i, h-1>] - inventory[<i, h>] + backorder[<i, h>];
        }   
    } 

forall(<i, h> in order) {
        sum(<<w, i>, h> in assignment) J[<<w, i>, h>] == production[<i, h>];

      }       
}`
```